# Rubymotion Image Button event not firing

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Does anyone know why the button in the following RubyMotion code doesn't fire the say_something method when clicked ...

```
class HomeViewController < UIViewController
  def loadView
    self.view = UIImageView.alloc.init
  end

  def viewDidLoad
    view.image = UIImage.imageNamed('background.png')

    @action_button = UIButton.buttonWithType UIButtonTypeCustom
    @action_button.frame = [[100, 100], [224, 229]]
    @action_button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageNamed("home_button_green.png"), forState: UIControlStateNormal)
    @action_button.addTarget(self, action: :say_something, forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)

    view.addSubview @action_button
  end

  def say_something
    @alert_box = UIAlertView.alloc.initWithTitle("Hello World",
            message:"Hi",
            delegate: nil,
            cancelButtonTitle: "ok",
            otherButtonTitles:nil)

        # Show it to the user
        @alert_box.show
  end

  def viewDidAppear(animated)

  end


end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, the view needs to be told user interaction is allowed ...

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

This fixed the issue and the button now presses and event fires.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else coming across this. The only reason you had to set `userInteractionEnabled` was because you used an instance `UIImageView` as the viewController's view.